# How to change character encoding in php?

Tags: php, wordpress

i m developing one site using wordpress deepfocus theme in that i want to show header in hebrew text but if i change name of header links in hebrew then it can not show any thing (e.g if i change Home to " לשוב " then it dont display on front end.

Comment: Can you describe your problem more clearly? Does the text display clearly on any page?

Comment: Hi sory for late actualy i am using wordpress and deepfocus theme in my website and i want to show menu bar of front site in hebrew language when i type hebrew conversion of (home) insted of 'Home' then it does not display anything why?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that you're dealing with encoding on both the server side and client side.

The php manual has tons of character encoding functions. It's always useful working in UTF-8:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Also, if you've never seen this, it's worth a read.
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Thnks for reply but i am using UTF-8 characterset but not working if u take plain php page using UTF-8 encoding and echo any hebrew text then it show fine but in wordpress deepfocus it is not displaying

Comment: So make sure the plugin is using utf-8 encoded strings and if it uses a database at all that that also uses utf-8.

Comment: Yes the plugin encoding is utf-8 and also database encoding is utf8_general_ci.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you're sending the correct character set to the browser. (Right click, View Page Info in Firefox)

If the encoding is anything other than UTF-8, add this to your header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```